# nodejs app wont create server, says ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to run a nodejs app on my VPS but for somereason I get a ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT error.

Here is my code:

```
const http = require('http');

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.end();
});
server.on('clientError', (err, socket) => {
  socket.end('HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request\r\n\r\n');
});
server.listen(8000);
```

when i cd to my directory and do

> node index.js

, it gives me no error, but going to the browser and doing: `mysite.com:8000` gives me nothing. The connections times out

EDIT:
when i do `curl: enomshop.tk:8000`, I get some feedback. Its like i can access from the within the VPS but no access publicly

Comment: Check if 1) Your VPS allows port 8000 to be accessed. 2) Is there a specific IP your VPS instructs to bind to (by default node binds to 0.0.0.0, but some hosts require it to bind to a specific IP, like 192.xxx)

Comment: @laggingreflex and how exactly do i check for 1 and 2?

Comment: Make sure the port `8000` you are using is not already in use by another application. Try another port if that's the case.

Comment: I think the issue may be that your port is not opened in the VPS security settings. Please make sure the port `8000` is whitelisted for receiving traffic

Comment: @TarunLalwani your sugestion worked. With reference to https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159873/whitelist-source-ip-addresses-in-centos-7. You should consider adding it as an answer

Comment: What does your log/STDOUT say? Maybe there is an error there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the way you should go about resolving such issues

**Check if the process is running**

Run `ps aux | grep <process>` to check if your process is running

**Check if the port is being used**

Run `sudo netstat -plant | grep <port>` to check if port is listening or not and is it your process

**Check if the service is responding locally**

Run `telnet 127.0.0.1 <port>` and make sure you get a response. If you don't get a response then there are few possible issues you can look into

- The process is not started the server listening
- The process is not using the correct port
- There is a firewall that is blocking the port. There is [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159873/whitelist-source-ip-addresses-in-centos-7) for `firewall-cmd`, and [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/ufw-essentials-common-firewall-rules-and-commands) for ufw

**Check if the service is responding externally**

You can do `telnet <external ip> <port>`, if it doesn't work then there few things you should check below

- Make sure your server is binding to `0.0.0.0` or `<private ip>` and not `127.0.0.1`
- Make sure the VPS server you are hosting on, has your `<port>` enabled for communication. This is different for each service provider

If you follow these steps, it would solve most common network issues in such cases

Comment: The above steps really helped me narrow down the issue. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. To resolve that, just open up / allow the port from network security group (VPS) or Firewall to worldwide access.

And check `telnet mysite.com port`, it worked for me. Kindly let me know if you still face any issue, I will try to help further.

Answer (score -1):

You will need to open up the 8000 port on your VPS or redirect the traffic from any open port on VPS to 8000